# Can Bing News search return the news last year?

Tags: api, bing, azure-cognitive-services, bing-news-search-api

I am looking into Bing News Search, and my testing results (with a free trial api-key) only contains articles in the last month. However I would like to get articles from last 1 or 2 years.

for example:

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news/search?count=100&q=AMD+AND+product&since=1451606400&sortBy=Date
```

The document only mentioned use a 'freshness' as the filter with day/week/month options but no year.

Can I do that with Bing search? If I can, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way. One alternate way to do this is by using trending topics with "sortBy" option and then jump to the last set of results using "offset" parameter.

Another - less preferred - alternate way is to use datPublished field in JSON and parse results - may also help you to use "offset" parameter with bigger "count" number to go to slightly lower ranked results, which maybe older. More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v7-reference.